# Spark HBase to Google Dataproc and Bigtable migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have HBase Spark job running at AWS EMR cluster. Recently we moved to GCP. I transferred all HBase data to BigTable. Now I am running same Spark - Java/Scala job in Dataproc. Spark job failing as it is looking `spark.hbase.zookeeper.quorum` setting.

Please let me know, how without code change I can make my spark job to run successfully with BigTable.

Regards,
Neeraj Verma

Comment: Have you tried by explicitly exporting the hbase-site.xml to SPARK_CLASSPATH ?

Comment: @gruby My question is , I need to avoid hbase as i want to use Bigtable. So is there any setting in hbase-site.xml that i can changeso that i can  use Bigtable

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/simple-cli/src/main/resources/hbase-site.xml

Comment: Could you include additional information please: what version of hbase are you linking against? Whats the full error stacktrace? What version of Dataproc?

Comment: For posterity, we're discussing this issue on the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/XzzHsJ7h6H0

Comment: thanks everyone. I am new in this world so learning basic things. issue resolved more update on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/XzzHsJ7h6H0

Comment: @nxverma , could you add an answer saying what help you to solve the problem? So if other users have the same issue, the know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While BigTable shares same principles and same Java API is available as HBase, it is not sharing its wire protocol. So standard HBase Client won't work (zookeeper error looks like you are trying to connect to BigTable via HBase client). Instead, you need to modify your program to use [BigTable-specific client](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/bigtable-and-hbase). It implements same Java interfaces as HBase, but requires custom google jars in classpath and few property overrides to enable it.